# Why am I getting three "Illegal Configuration" errors within my project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a project where I have three labels in a custom cell prototype class (subclass of UITableViewCell) that are linked to three label outlets in the custom cell's .h file.

Then in my main viewcontroller class (which houses the prototype cells and is a subclass of UITableViewController) my delegate method that interacts with these labels looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    int row = indexPath.row;

    cell.articleTitle.text = self.articleTitles[row];
    cell.articleURL.text = self.articleURLs[row];
    cell.articlePreview.text = self.articleURLs[row];

    return cell;
}
```

Yet I get these three errors:

```
Connection "articleURL" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.
Connection "articlePreview" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.
Connection "articleTitle" cannot have a prototype object as its destination.
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm so confused.

Comment: It is just what the error message is telling you. You cannot link a UITableViewController's property to views in a cell. This is because there may be more than one instance of the cell at a time. (The framework would not know if you only plan for one). Connect the views to outlets within a custom UITableViewCell subclass which may have the TableView or the TableViewController as delegate and hand forward the information by calling a method in the controller. Sounds complicated but is rather straight forward. Though, I too, don't like it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be connecting the Label outlets wrong in your project. I assume that  labels `articleURL`, `articlePreview` and `articleTitle`  are defined in the `UITableViewCell`. They should be connected for outlets in the corresponding `customTableViewCell` class not in the `UIViewController`.  As you are referencing `self.articleTitles` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it suggests  that you are connecting them as outlets of current class not the `customTableViewCell` class. It is good idea to define your customTableCell as a property to your current class which is having UITableView's Delegate implemented.

Have a look at [TableView Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) for details.

Comment: The outlets are in and connected to the customTableViewCell class, UIViewController only has a basic model with some starter data, which is self.articleTitles/URLs/previews.

Comment: And oddly enough, even when I delete all the labels from Interface Builder the errors still remain...

Comment: Have you tried, for example, cleaning your project? Or searching your xibs (textually) for other outlets with those names?

Comment: Why does it keep needing to be cleaned? >_< Yes, that worked, thank you. Argh, Xcode.